# Does anyone know how i can make the dropdown menu display horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: html, css

i would like my dropdown menu to display horizontally meaning that the menu is displayed in a list format

I have tried altering the css by playing around with the position function as well as the padding function but i cannot seem to get even close to what i would like. I have also messed around with the display function hoping that it would make a difference but it just made it worse so i decided to undo everything.

Here's my code

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Our Story</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Specialists</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
              <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DBS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }

nav ul li a {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in;
  transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown links */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

/* Show the dropdown content when hovering over the dropdown */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to `display: flex` your `.dropdown-content` as well, and specify a [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  ...
}
```

```css
nav ul {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }

nav ul li a {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in;
  transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown links */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

/* Show the dropdown content when hovering over the dropdown */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Our Story</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Specialists</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DBS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I have a couple more questions if you don't mind? I am trying to move my dropdown menu and the links within the dropdown towards the left and i am trying to embed a custom arrow icon next to 'Specialists' as an indication that it is a dropdown menu